# Flatten expression algorithm

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I cant find any good algorithm to flatten values given in dict. My expression is a string with 'variables'. Each variable can be a number or another variable i.e:
My dict is

```
map = {
    'a': 4,
    'b': 6,
    'c': 'a+b',
    'd': 'c+a+4'
}
```

and expression can be like this:

`first = 'a + b' # result should be: '4 + 6'`

`secound = 'd PLUS c' # result '4+6+4+4 PLUS 4+6'`

I dont want evaluate this result. I wonder how to replace (flatten?) such variables by real numbers (from map dict)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expression replacement ([`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) or [`RegexpObject.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.sub) which accept not only a replacement string, but also replacement function as a second parameter):

```
import re

def flatten(expression, mapping):
    pattern = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, mapping)))
    while pattern.search(expression):
        expression = pattern.sub(lambda m: mapping[m.group()], expression)
    return expression

mapping = {
    'a': 4,
    'b': 6,
    'c': 'a+b',
    'd': 'c+a+4'
}

# Convert all values to strings.
mapping = {key: str(mapping[key]) for key in mapping}
```

usage:

```
>>> flatten('a + b', mapping)
'4 + 6'
>>> flatten('d PLUS c', mapping)
'4+6+4+4 PLUS 4+6'
```

BTW, don't use `map` as a variable name. It will shadows builtin function `map`.